# Problems with subquery in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with a problem in MySql, please help me.

In this example I have two tables, one with the results of a bunch of competitors and one that defines which three competitors that makes a team. In reality I have a number of other tables as well, but they are not really needed to describe this problem.

```
Table with results for each competitor
| competitor_id | result1 | result2 | result3 | result4 |
|       1       |    1    |    1    |    1    |     1   |
|       2       |    1    |    2    |    2    |     1   |
|       3       |    2    |    3    |    2    |     1   |
|       4       |    1    |    5    |    3    |     2   |
|       5       |    4    |    3    |    2    |     3   |
|       6       |    3    |    2    |    1    |     2   |
|       7       |    2    |    1    |    4    |     2   |
|       8       |    2    |    1    |    2    |     1   |
|       9       |    1    |    2    |    3    |     2   |

Table showing teams
| team_id | competitor1 | competitor3 | competitor3 |
|    1    |      1      |       3     |       4     |
|    2    |      2      |       8     |       9     |
|    3    |      7      |       6     |       5     |
```

I would now like to create a query that gives me the total sum of each team. I need to have it i one query (maybe with subqueries) because I need to sort desc on the total result.

In other words, I need a result set giving me team.id sorted desc on the total result of each team.

Anyone?

EDIT: Here's an update showing the desired result

First, let´s sum the results of each competitor:

```
Competitor 1: 1+1+1+1=4
Competitor 2: 1+2+2+1=6
Competitor 3: 2+3+2+1=8
Competitor 4: 1+5+3+2=11
Competitor 5: 4+3+2+3=12
Competitor 6: 3+2+1+2=8
Competitor 7: 2+1+4+2=9
Competitor 8: 2+1+2+1=6
Competitor 9: 1+2+3+2=8
```

Then let's look at the team table.

```
Team 1 consists of competitors 1, 3 and 4.  
Team 2 consists of competitors 2, 8 and 9.  
Team 3 consists of competitors 7, 6 and 5.  

Total sum of team with id = 1 is 4+8+11=23  
Total sum of team with id = 2 is 6+6+8=20  
Total sum of team with id = 3 is 9+8+12=29
```

Given all of this, I would like my result set to be

```
| id | team_sum |
| 3  |    29    |
| 1  |    23    |
| 2  |    20    |
```

Comment: The "total sum for each team" you mean the total number of competitions that competitors in a team participated or the number of competitors in a team? Although I doubt it would be the latter given that you have 3 columns of competitors in your teams table. Or probably you mean the total result for each group?

Comment: Can you post desired result based on your sample data?

Comment: Is it ok to redesign your database like instead of Teams with competitor it should simply be TeamID and TeamName on Team table and then another Table for Competitors with CompetitorID and TeamID in that way that would be the easiest to query your database. Besides it is more flexible to add members or delete members from a team.

Comment: Yes, detailed suggestions of redesign are welcome. I would appreciate very much if you can give my any example queries using that solution.

Comment: I find it difficult to go over data; if you could add your schema and data to http://sqlfiddle.com/ I will help you

Comment: Okey, here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d006

Comment: I redesign your database wherein you have only Competitors table with TeamID and Team table with TEamID and Team_Name and the query would be much easier like this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc64/1

Comment: any time you see numbered columns, you know yo're in trouble - you design is not [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form): Create a child table to hold the results.

Comment: I hate my numbered columns. I know it's not an 'ok' way to do it. Do you have an alternative solution to show me?

Comment: @peltors Have you tried my solution without the numbered at least for your Team but I just leave your competitors numbered column as it is.

Comment: @Edper Not yet, but I will try it before the end of the day. Your help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not redesign your database like you have only two tables one for `competitors` and one for `team` like :

```
Competitors Table:
`competitor_id`, `team_id`, `result1`, `result2`, `result3`, `result4`

Team Table:
`team_id`, `team_name`
```

And your query would be very easy like:

```
SELECT A.team_id, B.team_name, SUM(result1+result2+result3+result4) as TotalResult
FROM competitors A
INNER JOIN team B
ON A.team_id=B.team_id
GROUP BY A.team_id, B.team_name
```

See my [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc64/1)